# Validation using Multi Select Picklist

Tags: validation

I have Penthouse Object. In that, I kept Amenities as multi select picklist field.
 According to my task, Three of my amenities such as "false ceiling, wooden flooring and french windows " should be selected and it is mandatory.
 I want to validate that field i.e Is that field contains these three amenities or not.

If not, error should be displayed.
 What i wanna do now?

Comment: Hi @Sam, what have you tried so far and where are you stuck ?

Comment: Hi Vijay, I have tried the below formula. 
 !INCLUDES(amenities_c,"False Ceiling")&& !INCLUDES(amenities_c,"French Windows")&& !INCLUDES(amenities_c,"Wooden Flooring")

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the information as opposed to a comment.

Comment: Please clarify why you and another user are repeatedly asking [the same questions](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/294183/multislect-picklist-value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write validation rule on multi picklist field and it will look like below

```
NOT(AND(IF(INCLUDES(amenities__c, "false ceiling"),true,false),
IF(INCLUDES( amenities__c, "wooden flooring"),true,false),
IF(INCLUDES( amenities__c, "french windows"),true,false)))
```

[image]